# If/elif statement only gives me one answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

This is my code for a shop in my Python RPG game. Whatever value I select, the code executes the things for if I typed dagger. It also never tells me that I have insufficient funds. Always the same answer

```
global gcredits
dagger = Item('Iron dagger', 5, 5)
sword = Item('Iron sword', 10, 12)
armour = Item('Iron Armour', 15, 20)


print ("Welcome to the shop! Buy all your amour and weapon needs here!")
print ("You have",gcredits,"Galactic Credits!")

print (dagger.name,': Cost:', dagger.value,'Attack points:', dagger.hvalue)
print (sword.name,': Cost:', sword.value,'Attack points:', sword.hvalue)
print (armour.name,': Cost:', armour.value,'Attack points:', armour.hvalue)

choice = input('What would you like to buy?').upper()

if choice == 'DAGGER' or 'IRON DAGGER' or 'IRONDAGGER':
    print ("You have selected the Iron Dagger.")
    if gcredits >= 5:
        print ('Purchase successful')
        gcredits = gcredits - 5

        dEquip = True
        shop()
    elif gcredits < 5:
        print ("You have got insufficient funds")
        shop()

elif choice == 'SWORD' or 'IRON SWORD' or 'IRONSWORD':
    if gcredits >= 10:
        print ('Purchase successful')
        gcredits = gcredits - 10

        sEquip = True
        shop()
    elif gcredits < 10:
        print ("You have got insufficient funds")
        shop()

elif choice == 'ARMOUR' or 'IRON ARMOUR' or 'IRONARMOUR':
    if gcredits >= 15:
        print ('Purchase successful')
        gcredits = gcredits - 15

        aEquip = True
        shop()
    elif gcredits < 15:
        print ("You have got insufficient funds")
        shop()

else:
    print ("That is not an item. Try again.")
    shop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you write your `OR` condition is wrong:

```
if choice == 'DAGGER' or 'IRON DAGGER' or 'IRONDAGGER':
```

It is supposed to be:

```
if choice == 'DAGGER' or choice == 'IRON DAGGER' or choice == 'IRONDAGGER':
```

or, more Pythonically:

```
if choice in ('DAGGER', 'IRON DAGGER', 'IRONDAGGER'):
```

When you do `if choice == 'DAGGER' or 'IRON DAGGER'` what happen is that you do **not** check if

1. your `choice` is `DAGGER` is `True` or if
2. your `choice` is `IRON DAGGER` is `True`

but you check if

1. your `choice` is `DAGGER` is `True` or
2. if `IRON DAGGER` is `True`

Note that `if 'IRON DAGGER'` will always return `True`:

```
if 'IRON DAGGER': #this is always true
```

Comment: Or since it's Python, you can avoid repeating the variable name over and over with `if choice in ('DAGGER', 'IRON DAGGER', 'IRONDAGGER'):`; CPython even specifically optimizes this case to avoid building the `tuple` live on each pass by storing it as a constant that can be loaded all at once without construction.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah yes, that is certainly more Pythonical way of doing it...